# Pandas Dataframe calculate Time Difference for each Day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.07.2019, 06:21:33', '01.07.2019, 06:32:01', '01.07.2019, 06:57:33', '01.07.2019, 07:24:33',
              '01.07.2019, 08:26:25', '01.07.2019, 09:12:44', '01.07.2019, 10:02:01', '01.07.2019, 12:22:22',
              '02.07.2019, 13:26:25', '02.07.2019, 13:48:44', '02.07.2019, 14:02:01', '02.07.2019, 14:32:22'
             ]
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 
                 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['Bayer', 'Bayer', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'Geco' , 'Geco',
               'Test', 'Test', 'Test2', 'Test2','Test3', 'Test3'],
               'Group': ['1', '1', '2','2','3','3','4','4','5','6','7','7']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and i calculated the time difference like that:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], dayfirst=True)
df["d1"] = df.groupby("Name")["Time"].diff().shift(-1).fillna("")
df["d2"] = (
    df.groupby((df["Action"] == "Closed").cumsum())["Time"]
    .diff()
    .shift(-1)
    .fillna("")
)
```

my output:

```
                 Time   Action  Name    Group        d1         d2
0   2019-07-01 06:21:33 Opened  Bayer   1       0 days 00:10:28 
1   2019-07-01 06:32:01 Closed  Bayer   1                 0 days 00:25:32
2   2019-07-01 06:57:33 Opened  ITM     2       0 days 00:27:00 
3   2019-07-01 07:24:33 Closed  ITM     2                 0 days 01:01:52
4   2019-07-01 08:26:25 Opened  Geco    3       0 days 00:46:19 
5   2019-07-01 09:12:44 Closed  Geco    3                 0 days 00:49:17
6   2019-07-01 10:02:01 Opened  Test    4       0 days 02:20:21 
7   2019-07-01 12:22:22 Closed  Test    4                 1 days 01:04:03
8   2019-07-02 13:26:25 Opened  Test2   5       0 days 00:22:19 
9   2019-07-02 13:48:44 Closed  Test2   6                 0 days 00:13:17
10  2019-07-02 14:02:01 Opened  Test3   7       0 days 00:30:21 
11  2019-07-02 14:32:22 Closed  Test3   7
```

so the main focus is on d2 how can i add the day into the condition so that the calculation stops if the day ends? For example in line 7 should be nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for the day part is conditionally applied whether zero or more than zero in order to get rid of the values having days with more than zero such as

```
df["dff"] = df.groupby((df["Action"] == "Closed").cumsum())["Time"].diff().shift(-1)

df.loc[ df["dff"].astype('timedelta64[D]') == 0, "d2" ] = df["dff"].fillna("")
df.loc[ df["dff"].astype('timedelta64[D]') > 0, "d2" ] = 'NaN'
```